# React JSON Schema Focus on error field after submit

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I am trying to get [React JSON Schema](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to focus on the first field with an error after submit and I am not able to find any way to do so.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `onError` prop you can use according to the [docs](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/form-props/#onerror). If an error exists, you can use the focus method such as `document.getElementById("myTextField").focus()` to that first element.